# R: Variable lengths differ in Wilcoxon test

Tags: r

Trying to see if there is a significant difference in DAPI between the DMSO treatment and the EPZ treatment. My dataset has three variables and each treatment group has a different number of individuals. Here's data I've made up to give a picture:

- Treatment DAPI DAPO DAPU
- DMSO       20   30   40
- DMSO       24   26   42
- DMSO       23   24   39
- EPZ0.5uM   10   25   22
- EPZ0.5uM   12   24   22
- EPZ0.5uM   14   24   30
- EPZ0.5uM   20   19   32

(apologies I don't know how to format a table on stackoverflow)

After importing the dataset I've done this:
`EPZDMSO<-EPZdata[which(EPZdata$Treatment=="DMSO"),]`
`EPZ0.5uM<-EPZdata[which(EPZdata$Treatment=="EPZ0.5uM"),]`

Tried to use wilcox.text:
`wilcox.test(EPZDMSO$DAPI~EPZ0.5uM$DAPI,data=EPZdata,mu=0,alt="two.sided",conf.int=T,conf.level=0.95,paired=FALSE,exact=T,correct=T)`

But get this error message:
`Error in model.frame.default(formula = EPZDMSO$DAPI ~ EPZ0.5uM$DAPI, data = EPZdata) : variable lengths differ (found for 'EPZ0.5uM$DAPI')`

Do I need to correct for unbalanced data?

Comment: You can use `dput` for making a reproducible copy of your data. That helps us to run your code for ourselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, just need to subset to the DAPI column.

Here's the man page, `help(wilcox.test)`.

> wilcox.test(x, y = NULL,
>               alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
>               mu = 0, paired = FALSE, exact = NULL, correct = TRUE,
>               conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, ...)
>
> Arguments
>
> x  numeric vector of data values. Non-finite (e.g., infinite or missing) values will be omitted.
>
> y  an optional numeric vector of data values: as with x non-finite
>   values will be omitted.

So to compare two groups with `wilcox.test`, `x` and `y` should be vectors of data.

```
wilcox.test(x = EPZDMSO$DAPI, y = EPZ0.5uM$DAPI,
            mu=0, alt="two.sided", conf.int=T, conf.level=0.95,
            paired=FALSE, exact=T, correct=T)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  EPZDMSO$DAPI and EPZ0.5uM$DAPI
W = 11.5, p-value = 0.07446
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  0 14
sample estimates:
difference in location 
              9.497565
```

**Data**

```
EPZdata <- structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("DMSO", "EPZ0.5uM"), class = "factor"), DAPI = c(20L, 
24L, 23L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 20L), DAPO = c(30L, 26L, 24L, 25L, 24L, 
24L, 19L), DAPU = c(40L, 42L, 39L, 22L, 22L, 30L, 32L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
EPZDMSO<-EPZdata[which(EPZdata$Treatment=="DMSO"),]
EPZ0.5uM<-EPZdata[which(EPZdata$Treatment=="EPZ0.5uM"),]
```